# Resources$NotFoundException for XML vector drawable on API 19

Tags: android, android-resources, android-vectordrawable

I'm trying to load an XML vector drawable with the following code:

```
int px = Application.get().getResources()
                .getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.bikeshare_small_marker_size);

Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(px, px, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

Canvas c = new Canvas(bitmap);
Drawable shape = ContextCompat.getDrawable(Application.get(), R.drawable.bike_marker_small);
shape.setBounds(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
shape.draw(c);
```

Here is the `bike_marker_small.xml` file:

```
<vector android:height="24dp" android:viewportHeight="210.0"
    android:viewportWidth="210.0" android:width="24dp" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <path android:fillColor="#ffffff"
        android:pathData="M105.03,104.97m-53.84,0a53.84,53.84 117.34,1 1,107.67 0a53.84,53.84 117.34,1 1,-107.67 0"
        android:strokeAlpha="1" android:strokeColor="#3a4677" android:strokeWidth="1.46500003"/>
    <path android:fillAlpha="1" android:fillColor="#3a4677"
        android:pathData="M105.1,104.67m-47.53,0a47.53,47.53 118.07,1 1,95.06 0a47.53,47.53 118.07,1 1,-95.06 0"
        android:strokeAlpha="1" android:strokeColor="#000000" android:strokeWidth="0.26458332"/>
</vector>
```

On Android 6, 7, and 8 this works fine.  However, when I try to run the app on an API 19 (Android 4.4) emulator or device, I get the following:

```
 android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/bike_marker_small.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f08005f. 
 If the resource you are trying to use is a vector resource, you may be referencing it in an unsupported way. 
 See AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled() for more info.
      at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2101)
      at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:700)
      at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:353)
      at org.onebusaway.android.map.googlemapsv2.bike.BikeStationOverlay.createBitmapFromShape(BikeStationOverlay.java:195)
      at org.onebusaway.android.map.googlemapsv2.bike.BikeStationOverlay.(BikeStationOverlay.java:87)
      at org.onebusaway.android.map.googlemapsv2.BaseMapFragment.setupBikeStationOverlay(BaseMapFragment.java:474)
```

I have the following in my `build.gradle`:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 86
        versionName "2.3.1"

        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
...
```

Why isn't this working?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Trying creating the drawable `shape` using `VectorDrawableCompat.create()` instead of `ContextCompat.getDrawable()`:

```
Drawable shape = VectorDrawableCompat.create(
    Application.get().getResources(),
    R.drawable.bike_marker_small, 
    Application.get().getTheme()
);
```

Comment: You asked 4 mins ago and you answered yourself 4 mins ago... Really?

Comment: Yes, this format is encouraged - see https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer.  I don't get any points for it, but at least this way it's documented for others to find the answer.

Comment: BTW - @AlexTa did you down vote the question? It's had two down votes without comment and I don't understand why.

Comment: No I didn't. I only down vote spam or abusive question/answers.

Comment: Great self-answer! Upvoted both, question and answer.

Answer (score 3):

Answer from Sean Barbeau is defintely great, although I'd like to add something that happened to me and that could cause troubles to other people trying to figure out what's going on with `VectorDrawable` on API 19 or API 20.

I created a method to obtain the `VectorDrawable` as `Drawable` for cases when I don't need/want to use them as `Drawable`, but as `Bitmap`, for example. This method would work for Android versions >= API 19.

This is the Kotlin method (look at the end for the improved version):

```
fun getDrawable(context:Context, drawableId: Int): Drawable {
    var drawable: Drawable?

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        drawable = VectorDrawableCompat.create(context.resources, drawableId, context.theme)
    } else {
        drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, drawableId)
    }

    return drawable
}
```

Basically, I pass the context (since this method would be a helper method and will be in a class without a `Context` or an `Activity`) and the resource ID of the `VectorDrawable`.

It could happen, that you directly call this helper method with the resource ID using the R namespace, like this:

```
ImageUtils.Companion.getDrawable(
    getBaseContext(),
    R.drawable.your_vector_drawable
)
```

However, it could be as well that you generate the resource ID dynamically, similar to:

```
@DrawableRes val resourceID = context.resources.getIdentifier(
    "resource_prefix_" + type,
    "drawable",
    context.packageName
)
```

And then call to the helper method, in the same way as before, using the resourceID variable:

```
ImageUtils.Companion.getDrawable(
    getBaseContext(),
    resourceID
)
```

If you do it this way, while on API < 21, the dynamically generated resource ID would most likely be a PNG. And the helper method will fail, because it expected a XML (SVG). You can fix it by requesting a normal `Drawable` (and not a `VectorDrawable`), by catching the `NotFoundException` that will be raised and just getting a `Drawable`. This is the final helper method:

```
fun getDrawable(context:Context, drawableId: Int): Drawable {
    var drawable: Drawable?
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        try {
            drawable = VectorDrawableCompat.create(context.resources, drawableId, context.theme)
        } catch (ex: Resources.NotFoundException) {
            drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, drawableId)
        }
    } else {
        drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, drawableId)
    }

    return drawable
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use `AppCompatResources.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.drawable_id);` which internally does all the trick for you.

This works with:

1. normal `Drawables`s
2. `VectorDrawable`s,
3. `AnimatedVectorDrawable`s
4. `AnimatedStateListDrawable`s

You need the [appcompat](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/appcompat#declaring_dependencies) library to do this